# Tensorflow 2.2.0 and Keras save model / load model problems

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, save, load

After adding a custom loss function as @tf.function to my keras DQN, keras models stopped loading (seems to save model, but cannot reload model). Documentation suggests this is really simple, but...

Various SO answers suggest that models trained using one Keras version cannot be loaded into other Keras version. So I uninstalled Keras 2.4.3 (from Anaconda env), to avoid any confusion, and trying to solely model and save/load using Tensorflow-keras.

So, now trying to save a Tensorflow-keras model and then load that model again, but will not re-load, various errors (below). Environment is Anaconda3 python3.8 (with Keras 2.4.3, then uninstalled this) and Tensorflow 2.2.0 (containing Keras 2.3.0-tf).

Is there some solution to simply save a model and then reload a model in tf 2.2.0 (with keras 2.3.0-tf)?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,  LSTM, Masking, Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Then all tf.keras modelling and save / load should be done by Keras-2.3.0-tf, from within Tensorflow. Model save is done with:

```
agent.model.save(os.path.join(pathOUT, PAIR, 'models' + modelNum, modelFolder), 
save_format='tf')
```

But generates deprecation warning during save:

```
2020-11-26 00:19:03.388858: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:329] Sets are not currently 
considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\..mypath......\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1813: calling 
BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with 
constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
Saved an Intermediate model...
```

Then attempt to load model with:

```
model = load_model(LOAD_MODEL)
```

but generates error during loading:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduction'
```

Again, is there some solution to simply save a model and then reload a model in tf 2.2.0 (with keras 2.3.0-tf)?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File mypath, line 851, in <module>
  agent = DQNAgent()   
File mypath, line 266, in __init__
  self.model = self.create_model()
File mypath, line 336, in create_model
  model = load_model(LOAD_MODEL)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 190, in load_model
  return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 116, 
  in load
  model = tf_load.load_internal(path, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 602, in 
  load_internal
  loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto,
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 188, 
  in __init__
  super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 123, in __init__
  self._load_all()
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 209, 
   in _load_all
 self._layer_nodes = self._load_layers()
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 312, 
  in _load_layers
  layers[node_id] = self._load_layer(proto.user_object, node_id)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 335, 
  in _load_layer
  obj, setter = self._revive_from_config(proto.identifier, metadata, node_id)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 349, 
  in _revive_from_config
  obj = self._revive_metric_from_config(metadata, node_id)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 441, 
  in _revive_metric_from_config
  obj = metrics.deserialize(
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 3345, in deserialize
  return deserialize_keras_object(
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 361, in 
  deserialize_keras_object
  (cls, cls_config) = class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 327, in 
  class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
  deserialized_objects[key] = deserialize_keras_object(
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 375, in 
  deserialize_keras_object
  return cls.from_config(cls_config)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 628, in from_config
  return super(MeanMetricWrapper, cls).from_config(config)
File mypath\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 655, in 
  from_config
  return cls(**config)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduction'
```

Additional code:
Custom loss function (trying to implement gradient ascent, by 'flipping' the error gradient), have tried this in various locations (within same agent class as model, outside agent class, other.

```
@tf.function
def positive_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return -1 * tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred)
```

The Sequential model I am using is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64956763/how-to-implement-gradient-ascent-in-a-keras-dqn/64961297?noredirect=1#comment114869236_64961297)

Comment: Whats this `"tf"`format you are trying to save to? I am not sure about your error but I'm running tf 2.1.0 and tf.keras 2.2.4-tf and using `tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential.save("modelname.h5")` to save and `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model("modelname.h5")` to load the model.

Comment: In effort to resolve save/load problems I was trying to be as explicit as possible. Although in tf2.2.* save_format default is tf format (from keras docs: 'save_format: Either 'tf' or 'h5', indicating whether to save the model to Tensorflow SavedModel or HDF5. Defaults to 'tf' in TF 2.X, and 'h5' in TF 1.X.'). Are you sure your save format is h5 if default is tf and you have not spec'd h5? Have tried your save/load format, but no solution for  my code.thx

Comment: @MarkD, Does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31850#issuecomment-578566637) answer your query ? If not can you please share complete code to replicate your issue. As I have successfully save and load sample model as per above specified versions in colab with custom loss.Thanks!

Comment: Thx. A previous (unfortunately) deleted post pointed to this solution. But it does not resolve the keyword argument 'reduction' error on reload. I seem to have some problem with using a decorated custom loss function in my model when saving and loading using tf.keras (2.3.0-tf). I have currently reverted to using keras 2.4.0 and an undecorated function, with compile=False on reload of model. Will add additional code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have resolved/bypassed the original keyword argument 'reduction' error by REMOVING the MeanSquareError() metric during model compile of original model. Original model:

```
model.compile(loss=positive_mse,
              optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE, decay=DECAY),
              metrics=[tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()])
```

From the Keras docs: "*Note that this is an important difference between loss functions like tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error and default loss class instances like tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError: the function version does not perform reduction, but by default the class instance does.*"

The MeanSquaaredError loss class function is passing a 'reduction' keyword during evaluation of loss over a minibatch. Removing this metric allows model to be reloaded without error.

Comment: but what if you mean this metric? Do you mean you substitute MeanSquaredError for mean_squared_error?

Comment: No. Deleted, not substituted. Am only using loss and optimizer keyword parameters, not using metrics. Am recording metrics from model in real time in data file, and simply visualising in matplotlib.

Comment: why not use [tf.keras.metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics)

Comment: Have always had problems with Tensorflow metrics and Tensorboard (have never been stable, Tensorboard especially, on my installations)...so have just been using custom loss outputs